# Matplotlib Add_subplot() function not working within a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, user-defined-functions

I have created a user-defined function that will call saved images from a specific directory and make a single subplot with them. Rather than returning a 2x3 subplot, the code returns a 6x1 subplot. I printed the counter to make sure that it's iterating through the correct values (which it is). Any suggestions?

```
def create_subplot(my_direc,name_vec):
     #name_vec = Vector with string variables of length n (nx1 or 1xn)
     #my_direc = Path of where individual .png files are stored

     counter = 1;
     for i in name_vec:
         genename = i.replace("/","_"); #Replace slashes in any gene names
         filname = my_direc + genename + '.png';
    
         fig = plt.figure()
         img = cv2.imread(filname); 
         img_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB); #convert image back to original color
    
         fig.add_subplot(2, 3, counter)
         plt.imshow(img_RGB)
         plt.axis('off'); plt.title("")
    
         print(counter)
         counter = counter + 1;
```

[image: Output from code]

Comment: Have you tried moving `fig = plt.figure()` out of the `for` loop?

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks for the help--glad it was an easy fix.